# URL(string:) возвращает nil при вызове со строкой содержащей

Tags: ios, foundation

URL(string:) возвращает nil при вызове со строкой содержащей
последний компонент с кириллицей

[https://somedomain.ru/upload/files/Оферта.pdf](https://somedomain.ru/upload/files/%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0.pdf)

это лечится как то кроме запросом заказчику предоставить альтернативный юрл
не содержащий кириллицу?

Comment: url encode не поможет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения корректного URL при наличии кириллицы необходимо преобразовать строку при помощи метода addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:):

```
let str = "https://somedomain.ru/upload/files/Оферта.pdf"
guard let encodedString = str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed) else {
    // Обработать неудачное преобразование
    fatalError()
}
guard let url = URL(string: encodedString) else {
    // Еще какая-то проблема
    fatalError()
}
print(url) // prints: https://somedomain.ru/upload/files/%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0.pdf
```